# Having Trouble with Webpage Resizing

Tags: html, css, resize

I have finished a webpage I am working on, but unfortunately, I've only designed it for a 1920x1080 monitor. Whenever the site is viewed on other window sizes/monitor resolutions, the page does not adjust properly. Could someone possibly fix this so that the page is scaled accordingly when the window size is changed or it is viewed on mobile? If anyone could fix the code so that it would adjust to any browser side, that would be great. I've been working on it for a while. Here's the entire page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Vortex Network</title>
</head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script>
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
}
</script>
<script>
    (function(){
      /**
        author: @manufosela
        2013/08/27    copyleft 2013

        ShootingStar class Main Methods:
          launch: launch shooting stars every N seconds received by param. 10 seconds by default.
          launchStar: launch a shooting star. Received options object by param with:
             - dir (direction between 0 and 1)
             - life (between 100 and 400)
             - beamSize (between 400 and 700)
             - velocity (between 2 and 10)
      **/

      ShootingStar = function( id ) {
        this.n = 0;
        this.m = 0;
        this.defaultOptions = { velocity:8, starSize:10, life:300, beamSize:400, dir:-1 };
        this.options = {};
        id = ( typeof id != "undefined" )?id:"";
        this.capa = ( $( id ).lenght > 0 )?"body":id;
        this.wW = $( this.capa ).innerWidth();
        this.hW = $( this.capa ).innerHeight();
      };

      ShootingStar.prototype.addBeamPart = function( x, y ) {
        this.n++;
        var name = this.getRandom( 100, 1 );
        $( "#star"+name ).remove();
        $( this.capa ).append( "<div id='star"+name+"'></div>" );
        $( "#star"+name ).append( "<div id='haz"+this.n+"' class='haz' style='position:absolute; color:#FF0; width:10px; height:10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:"+this.options.starSize+"px'>·</div>" );
        if ( this.n > 1 ) $( "#haz" + ( this.n - 1 ) ).css( { color:"rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" } );
        $( "#haz" + this.n ).css( { top: y + this.n, left: x + ( this.n * this.options.dir ) } );
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.delTrozoHaz = function() {
        this.m++;
        $( "#haz" + this.m ).animate( {opacity:0}, 75 );
        if ( this.m >= this.options.beamSize ) { $( "#ShootingStarParams" ).fadeOut( "slow" ); }
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.getRandom = function( max, min ) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.toType = function ( obj ) {
        if ( typeof obj === "undefined" ) { return "undefined"; /* consider: typeof null === object */ }
        if ( obj === null ) { return "null"; }
        var type = Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ).match( /^\[object\s(.*)\]$/ )[1] || '';
        switch ( type ) {
          case 'Number': if ( isNaN( obj ) ) { return "nan"; } else { return "number"; }
          case 'String': case 'Boolean': case 'Array': case 'Date': case 'RegExp': case 'Function': return type.toLowerCase();
        }
        if ( typeof obj === "object" ) { return "object"; }
        return undefined;
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.launchStar = function( options ) {
        if ( this.toType( options ) != "object" ) { options = {}; }
        this.options = $.extend( {}, this.defaultOptions, options );
        this.n=0;
        this.m=0;
        var i=0, l=this.options.beamSize,
            x=this.getRandom( this.wW - this.options.beamSize - 100, 100 ), y=this.getRandom( this.hW - this.options.beamSize - 100, 100 ),
            self = this;
        for( ; i<l; i++ ) { setTimeout( function(){ self.addBeamPart( x, y ); }, self.options.life + ( i * self.options.velocity ) ); }
        for( i=0; i<l; i++ ) { setTimeout( function(){ self.delTrozoHaz() }, self.options.beamSize + ( i * self.options.velocity ) ); }
        $( "#ShootingStarParams" ).html();
        $( "#ShootingStarParams" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.launch = function( everyTime ) {
        if ( this.toType( everyTime ) != "number" ) { everyTime = 2; }
        everyTime = everyTime * 1000;
        this.launchStar();
        var self = this;
        setInterval( function() {
          var options = {
            dir: ( self.getRandom( 1, 0 ))?1:-1,
            life: self.getRandom( 400, 100 ),
            beamSize: self.getRandom( 700, 400 ),
            velocity: self.getRandom( 10, 4 )
          }
          self.launchStar( options );
        }, everyTime );
      }

})();

</script>
   </div>
<style type="text/css">
#top-image {

    background:url('https://www.14denoviembre.es/img/stars_5.png') -25px -50px;
    position:fixed ;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
    z-index:98;
}

body { 
    color:#FFF; 
    height:55%; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    color:#FFF;
    min-width:100%; 
    width: auto !important;
 }

.stars {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url( http://www.14denoviembre.es/img/hori.png ), url( http://www.14denoviembre.es/img/stars_5.png ); 
    background-repeat: repeat-x,repeat-x repeat-y;
    transform:translate3D(0em, 0em, 0); 
    animation: stars 21s ease; 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

      }

.Icon {

    width: 100%;
    height: 19%;
    top: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    align-content: center;

}


.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#logo {
    height:auto;
}


.shadowfilter {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80));
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;

}

.shadowfilter:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 179, 0.8));
}

#thumbs {   
    position: relative;
    width: 52%;
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 10000;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
.status {   
    position: relative;
    height: 5%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 27%;
    border: 3px  solid #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 75px #ffffff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 75px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 75px #ffffff;
    z-index:99;

   }

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 5;
}
.floating{
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation-name: Floatingx;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: Floating;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes Floatingx{
    from {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translate(0, -0px);    }    
}

@-moz-keyframes Floating{
    from {-moz-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-moz-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-moz-transform: translate(0, -0px);}    
}


.scaling{
    float: center;
    -webkit-animation-name: scalex;
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: scale;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

    @-webkit-keyframes scalex{
        from {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);}
        65% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.0);}
        to {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);}    
    }

    @-moz-keyframes scale{
        from {-moz-transform: scale(0.9);}
        65% {-moz-transform: scale(1.0);}
        to {-moz-transform: scale(0.9);}    
    }
.zoom_img img{  
-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.2s ease-in; 
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in; 
-o-transition:-o-transform 0.2s ease-in;
}
.zoom_img img:hover{
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); 
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-o-transform:scale(1.1);
}
p {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
       color: #ae00de;
       font-size: 2.6em;
       margin:0px;
}
</style>
<body class="stars">
<div class="zoom_img">
    <div id="thumbs">
    <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/forum" id="single_image1"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/i03eeyw23/Forums_After.png" alt="Forums_Icon"/></a>


    <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/vote" id="single_image2"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/vshtalmtn/Vote_After.png" alt="Vote_Icon"/></a>

    <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/donate" id="single_image3"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/j4xgkciiz/Store_After.png" alt="Shop_Icon" height="200" width="190"/></a>

    <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/members" id="single_image4"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/ds8m67umj/Staff_After_2.png" alt="Staff_Icon" height="200" width="200"/></a>

    <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/bans" id="single_image5"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/5vo4xzj63/Bans_After_2.png" alt="Bans_Icon"/></a>

    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>​
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="Icon">
<img src="http://files.enjin.com/353719/module_header/10950667/background/Vortex-Network-Logonew.png" class="scaling" width="642" height="460"></img>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="status">
<p>play.vortexpvp.com</p>
</div>
    <div id="top-image"></div>
    <div id="ShootingStarParams"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ShootingStarClass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready( function(){
        var shootingStarObj = new ShootingStar( "body" );
            shootingStarObj.launch();
      });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS3 @media Rule**

you should apply **CSS3 @media Rule** to all the elements included in your website,

for example you have a #top-image style css:

```
#top-image {

    background:url('https://www.14denoviembre.es/img/stars_5.png') -25px -50px;
    position:fixed ;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
    z-index:98;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     #top-image {
        width:20%;
       height:20%;

    }
}
```

it will alter the #top-image's max width and height if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or wider.

> Learn the syntax before you apply it to your website: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp